# Alternative use of LISTAGG function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use `LISTAGG` function in sql query to show the data in group form. If there is any alternative function to `LISTAGG` that I can use in SQL query.

```
SELECT PersonName, LISTAGG(Z.t2, '; ')
FROM Z
GROUP BY PersonName
ORDER BY PersonName
```

Above query is in oracle and `LISTAGG` function is use in Oracle but I want to use its functionality in SQL Server.

Comment: "I want to use its functionality in sql" - do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? If so, what version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server